# Uploading Error for Ionic Project in Google Play Store

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, google-play

I am getting the following error when uploading my APK file to the Google Play Store.

> Your app currently targets API level 28 and must target at least API
> level 29 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for
> security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at
> least 29.

I tried changing the minSDKversion by going to the Project Structure

[image]

[image]

Even after changing these I am still getting the same error. Any help is highly appreciated..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
```